# Compare current value with previous value in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, angular2-template

I'm working in stock market application using ionic 3. I need to compare rates from object current and previous value and need to update background colors. I have currently written the code as like below, but some times color changes reflecting and most of the times colors are not reflecting.

```
export class HomePage {
    liverates: any = [];
    oldliverates: any = [];
    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.liverateservice.setcallback((data)=>{
            this.oldliverates = Object.create(this.liverates);
            let currentliverates: any = [];
            this.commodities.forEach((value, key) => {
                currentliverates.push({ 'com_id': com_id, 'com_name': com_name, 'buying_rate': buying_rate, 'selling_rate': selling_rate, 'delivery': deliverydays, 'is_coin': is_coin, 'comname_type': comname_type, 'comnametype_status': comnametype_status, 'deliverydays': deliverydays });
            });
            this.liverates = currentliverates;
     });
   }
}
```

And in my view

```
<div *ngFor="let liverate of liverates; let i = index">   
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-10 class="ratecol div_userwelcome trade_products_name">{{liverate.com_name}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-10  class="ratebox ratecol" [ngClass]="{'ratehigh' : (liverate.selling_rate > oldliverates[i].selling_rate), 'ratelow':(liverate.selling_rate < oldliverates[i].selling_rate), 'ratenormal': (liverate.selling_rate == oldliverates[i].selling_rate)}" (click)="gotoBookingPage(liverate.com_id, '1');">
      <div class="rates">{{liverate.selling_rate}}</div>
      <div class="sell_rtgs">{{liverate.comname_type}}</div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>        
    </div>
```

My css,

```
 .ratehigh{
        background: #008000;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .ratelow{
        background: #FF0000;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .ratenormal{
        background:null;
        color: #000000;
    }
```

When I check in console it is showing different rate in liverates and oldliverates object values if value get update, but not all the times rate comparison works well in my html file. Could you please any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: When `Angular3` was released :P

Comment: Instead of Ionic 3 I have mentioned angular 3

Comment: what is 'data' in your case? is it a json?

Comment: Yes it is json array object. Return from php json_encode